# Overflow-y not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, onclick, overflow

I want to make an onClick event on the link.

the code:

```
 <a onclick="document.getElementById('myBodyID').style.overflow-y='hidden'" title="my title">Anchor text</a>
```

Why isn't this working? I want to disable vertical scrolling when the link is clicked.

How could I fix this code? It is not working at the moment :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
document.getElementById('myBodyID').style.overflowY='hidden'
```

As CSS properties with special characters are camel cased.
You can also use brackets (`document.getElementById('myBodyID').style["overflow-y"]`).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `-` inside such a property literal. Instead, use the `[]` notation.

```
.style['overflow-y'] =
```

Currently, you're fetching `.style.overflow` and *subtracting* `y` (as with numbers), which does not make sense here.